# How to properly add options menu on a single fragment with navigation component without broke "up behavior"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm having some trouble to add options menu on a single fragment because it's breaking the navigation Up. Here my code

I have an single Activity with `NoActionBar` style and with this layout

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mainNavigationFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

in activity `onCreate` I make this setup for navigation

```
private fun setupNavigation() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationFragment)

        //each fragment of botton nav
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.actionSchedule,
                R.id.actionPayment,
                R.id.actionNotification,
                R.id.actionAccount))

        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

override fun onSupportNavigateUp() =
            findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationFragment).navigateUp()
```

on each botton nav fragment I have some destinations and everything work as expected.

Now I need to add an menu only on right most fragment of botton nav, then on this specific fragment I add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in onCreate and inflate menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but the menu does not appear.

Then I add `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` on activity `onCreate`.

Now the menu appear only on this fragment but it's broke all 'UP' (back arrow on toolbar) of any destination (the back arrow appears, but when i press nothing happens). If I remove `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` of activity the UP work again but not the toolbar menu.

What I need to do to make the menu work only in one fragment without broke anything else?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `setSupportActionBar`, you must use `setupActionBarWithNavController()`, not `toolbar.setupWithNavController` as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar).

Comment: I already try this before, but I try again and get this error when activity start
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.zumpy.passenger.debug/br.com.zumpy.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Sounds like you're calling `setSupportActionBar` after `setupActionBarWithNavController`. The order matters.

Comment: OMG, how I don't see that.. thanks @ianhanniballake, I was really calling the setSupportActionBar after

Answer (score 7):

if using toolbar do this:
in `Acitvity`:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var currentNavController: NavController? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my)

    currentNavController = findNavController(R.id.settingNavHost)

    currentNavController?.let {
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener {
                onBackPressed()
                true
            }.build()

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(it, appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

}

and in fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)

}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.action_save) {
        saveInfo()
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```